# Is there a way to create a python object that will be not sortable?

Tags: python

Is there a possibility to create any python object that will be not sortable? So that will be an exception when trying to sort a list of that objects?
I created a very simple class, didn't define any comparison methods, but still instances of this class are comparable and thus sortable. Maybe, my class inherits comparison methods from somewhere. But I don't want this behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

You could define a `__cmp__` method on the class and always raise an exception when it is called.  That might do the trick.

Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: Thanks for quick answer!
I found a recipe about the fastest way to remove duplicates from a sequence - http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52560/.
Check this commentary in code:
" If not possible, the sequence elements should enjoy a total
 ordering, and if list(s).sort() doesn't raise TypeError it's
 assumed that they do enjoy a total ordering.  Then unique() will
 usually work in O(N*log2(N)) time."
I cannot create an element which doesn't enjoy a total ordering. So is it a recipe author's error, or does he really knows something, that I don't know?

Comment: Why not just use `set()` to get a list–er, `set`–of unique elements?  Why are you using that recipe?  If you're using that recipe and you make your objects always raise an exception when they are sorted, that will use the third and worst way to determine the unique items.

Comment: Yes, understand that, I just want to know, if the author of the recipe is making something from nothing, or if he just tries handle all possible situations. 
So I want to know, in which cases the second solution fails (using sort) fails? First solution fails when objects are not hashable (sorting list of list for instance), but seems like there is no case when second solution fails.
By the way, your solution (use set() to get a list–er) also fails in case of not hashable lists.  

    >>> a = [[1,1], [1,2], [1,1]]
    >>> a = list(set(a))
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Okay, I'm stumped, too.  I don't know when the second solution would fail... I don't think I've ever run into a list of objects that always raised a `TypeError` when it was sorted.

Answer (score 1):

As Will McCutchen has mentioned, you can define a `__cmp__` method that raises an exception to prevent garden variety sorting. Something like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        raise Exception()

a = [Foo(), Foo(), Foo()]
a.sort()
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<stdin>", line 3, in __cmp__
Exception
```

However, you cannot truly prevent a developer from sorting a list of your objects. Using the `key` or `cmp` argument with `list.sort()` or with the built-in standalone `sorted()` function , anyone can circumvent the `__cmp__` method by using a custom comparison function or sorting key.

```
# continuing from above
>>> a = [Foo(), Foo(), Foo()]
>>> a
[<__main__.Foo object at 0x1004a3350>, <__main__.Foo object at 0x1004a3390>,
 <__main__.Foo object at 0x1004a33d0>]

>>> a.sort(key=id, reverse=True)
>>> # or a.sort(cmp=lambda a, b: cmp(id(b), id(a)))
>>> # or sorted(a, key=id)
>>> # etc...
[<__main__.Foo object at 0x1004a33d0>, <__main__.Foo object at 0x1004a3390>,
 <__main__.Foo object at 0x1004a3350>]
```

As others will point out, I'm not sure there's much value in trying to prevent someone from sorting an object. If this isn't just a curious itch you're trying to scratch, what's the use case for this?

Comment: You've been one minute faster. Almost exactly the same example code ;)

Answer (score 1):

The default list sorting uses the built-in `cmp()` function on its elements. The `cmp()` function checks if its arguments (2 elements from your list) have a `__cmp__()` method. If yes, this method is used for comparison. Otherwise, as in your case, the argument object IDs (return value of the built-in function `id()`) are used for comparison.

To let the sorting fail, you could define a comparison method which throws an Exception:

```
>>> class X(object):
...    def __cmp__(self, other):
...        raise StandardError # or whatever Exception you need
...
>>> l = [X(), X(), X()]
>>> l.sort()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in __cmp__
StandardError
```

Comment: That's a nice and clear answer! But does any object have a built-in function id()?

Comment: Object IDs are set internally by Python, not by an object's method. Typically, e.g. in C-based Python, it's simply the object's memory address (see also http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id).

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, in Python 3 the default will be for new items to not be comparable (and hence not sortable).  In Python 2, you have to explicitly create a `__cmp__` or `__lt__` method, as others have said.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just write a class that contains a list object and provides methods to access the data inside? By doing that you would effectively hide the list and therefore prevent them from sorting it.

Answer (score 0):

Sets don't have a total ordering

```
>>> s=set((1,2,3))
>>> t=set("abc")
>>> s<t
False
>>> t<s
False
>>>
```

But no exception is raise when you try to sort them

```
>>> sorted([s,t])
[set([1, 2, 3]), set(['a', 'c', 'b'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

The python sort algorithms use the `__lt__` special method. Keeping in mind that using the `cmp` and `key` arguments of the sorting function and methods, it is suggested that your class defines a method:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    raise NotImplementedError
```